# Hypercyclic operators in $L_p (0,\infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, chaos-theory

I'm pretty new to this area of study so if there are logical lacune in my proof (I'm sure there are many) please let me know.

This is material I'm self studying. I'm trying to adapt the methods used to show that $\ell_{p}$ has hypercyclic operators given [here](https://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781447121695-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1192237-p174139388) on p.40 Example 2.22.

Let $a>0$ and $|\lambda|>1$, on the space $X=L_p(0,\infty)$ endowed with the $p$-norm.

The operator

$T: X\to X\quad \text{where}\quad (Tf)(x)=\lambda f(x+a)$

is hypercyclic.

Proof. Let $U$ and $V$ be nonempty open subsets of $L_p(0,\infty)$. Since continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L_p(0,\infty)$ there exists functions $g(x)\in U$ and $N_1\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $g(x)=0$ if $x\notin [0,N_1]$. Similarly we can find a function $h(x)\in V$ where $h(x)=0$ if $x\notin [0,N_2]$. (Now I'm just going to try to find an interger N so that $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are both zero for $x\notin [0,N]$) Pick $M\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a\cdot M\geq \max\{N_1,N_2\}$ and let $N$ be the smallest integer such that $N\geq a\cdot M$. Then $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are both zero for $x\notin [0,N]$.

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary such that $a\cdot n \geq N$. Consider the function

$$ z(x) = \begin{cases} 
      g(x) & x\in (0,N] \\
      \lambda^{-n}h(x-an) &  x\in (an,N+an] \\
      0 & otherwise 
   \end{cases}$$

Note that $(T^nz)(x)=h(x)$ and 
    $$
\|z(x)-g(x)\|=\lambda^{-n}\|h(x-an)\|\to 0, n\to \infty
$$
    Thus for $n$ sufficently large, $z(x)\in U$ and $(T^nz)(x)=h(x)\in V$. This shows that $T$ is topologically transitive which implies $T$ hypercyclic since the underlying space is a separable Banach space.

Comment: The smallest integer such that $N\ge M$ is, in fact $M$....
MAybe $N\ge a\cdot M$?

Comment: You're right. Thank you I've changed it.

Comment: I have no more commnets. The proof seems correct to me.